# Load data when moving to selected tab

Tags: r, shiny

I have following app with modules. Data calculation function is fairly big and I hoped that it would not run both tabs at the launch, but waited running the runif (as an example) function when tab is clicked. I tried to follow https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinydashboard-render-only-the-clicked-tab/36493/2 example (I commented my try in the below example). But data will not be loaded. So how to modify this to not load all the data at the launch, but only when tab is selected? I feel like this has something to do with name spacing, but not sure how to correct it.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

module1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
    
    sideBar <- list(
      numericInput(inputId = ns('n'), label = 'N', value = 10, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
    )
    
    mainPanel <- list(
      card(
        uiOutput(ns("output"))
      )
    )
    
    page_sidebar(
      sidebar = sidebar(sideBar),
      layout_columns(
        col_widths = c(12),
        mainPanel[[1]]
      )
    )
}

module2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  sideBar <- list(
    numericInput(inputId = ns('n'), label = 'N', value = 10, min = 1, max = 100, step = 1)
  )
  
  mainPanel <- list(
    card(
      uiOutput(ns("output"))
    )
  )
  
  page_sidebar(
    sidebar = sidebar(sideBar),
    layout_columns(
      col_widths = c(12),
      mainPanel[[1]]
    )
  )
}

module1_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session) {
      
      data <- reactive({
        
        Sys.sleep(10)
        r <- runif(input$n)
        print(id)
        print(r)
        r
        
      })
      
      output$output <- renderText({
        req(data())
      })
      
    }
  )
}

module2_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session) {
      
      data <- reactive({
        
        Sys.sleep(10)
        r <- runif(input$n)
        print(id)
        print(r)
        r
        
      })
      
      output$output <- renderText({
        req(data())
      })
      
    }
  )
}


ui <- navbarPage("MAIN REPORT",
                 tabPanel("MODULE1", module1_ui(id = 'module_1')),
                 tabPanel("MODULE2", module2_ui(id = 'module_2'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  module1_server(id = 'module_1')
  module2_server(id = 'module_2')
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can clarify your issue, because shiny is lazy by default, and I only slightly modified your example (to make the modules run at all)
and module 1 loads by default as it is shown first given the tab init, and module 2 works on demand.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

module1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
   verbatimTextOutput(ns("output"))
  )
}

 


module1_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input,output,session) {
      
      data <- reactive({
        
        r <- runif(10)
        print(id)
        print(r)
        r
        
      })
      output$output <- renderText({
        req(data())
      })
      
    }
  )
}
ui <- navbarPage("MAIN REPORT",
                 # id = "tab",
                 tabPanel("MODULE1", module1_ui(id = 'module_1')),
                 tabPanel("MODULE2", module1_ui(id = 'module_2'))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  module1_server(id = 'module_1')
  module1_server(id = 'module_2')
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for great example, I think you're right and I have some missunderstandings. I have timed my function and it runs only for 20seconds and I have 5 tabs and when I open shiny, it takes roughly that 100seconds to open the first page, so I thought that it loads all those reactive functions behind. I will test and make better example, apologies for this. My reactive function takes in input (daterange) would that make it evaluate it even if tab is not open? But I will modify my question to better fit the situation.

Comment: You're right, it only takes roughly that 10 seconds to load that first page and not 20 which my app in real life does, so my problems are somewhere else. Thank you